# multiple unique constraint with OR operator

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, unique-constraint

Can we define multiple unique constraint with OR operator?

for example:

```
ADD CONSTRAINT unique_test UNIQUE (A, B) OR UNIQUE (B, C)
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: In addition to the database, can you give an example of your data?  This seems like a very unusual situation.

Comment: i use hibernate annotation with mysql.